# tinyMCE 4.0.8 onblure callback with inline option

Tags: tinymce-4

i am looking for a way to submit the changes of tinymce with inline option, this is the example of the inline, http://www.tinymce.com/tryit/inline.php.

so i need a method to setup some callback for the onblur of the inline editor.

this is the code that i used:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
tinymce.init({
    selector: "div.editable",
    inline: true,
    plugins: [
        "advlist autolink lists link image charmap print preview anchor",
        "searchreplace visualblocks code fullscreen",
        "insertdatetime media table contextmenu paste"
    ],
    toolbar: "insertfile undo redo | styleselect | bold italic | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | link image"
});
</script>

<div class="editable" style="width:100%; height:550px">
    This is an editable div element element.
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

found it, using the save plugin to add the save button, and the
save_onsavecallback callback to make the ajax request.

[reference](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Plugin%3asave)